# Computing the F test of two sets

Tags: c#, java, math, probability

Given two arrays of doubles, how Can I compute the F Test?

(F test is defined here: http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Ftest-Function.html)

I am looking for answer like this one:

[How can I efficiently calculate the binomial cumulative distribution function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095650/how-can-i-efficiently-calculate-the-binomial-cumulative-distribution-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement the algorithm as described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test). It's not difficult. Asking people for source code could be interpreted as lazy.

Comment: I read the wikipedia article. Still can't figure it out. Pseudo code is OK.