# How can I efficiently calculate the negative binomial cumulative distribution function?

Tags: algorithm, math, probability, binomial-cdf

This post is really helpful:

[How can I efficiently calculate the binomial cumulative distribution function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095650/how-can-i-efficiently-calculate-the-binomial-cumulative-distribution-function)

(Title = How can I efficiently calculate the binomial cumulative distribution function?)

However, I need the *negative* binomial cumulative distribution function.

Is there a way to tweek the code to get a *negative* cumulative distribution function?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CDF[NegativeBinomialDistribution[10%2C+3%2F4]%2C+4] is VERY efficient :)

Comment: You may find the code here http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/boost/math/distributions/negative_binomial.hpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the CDF by summing the terms of the PMF taking advantage of the recurrence relationship the terms satisfy.  The terms in the series are a little complicated, but the ratio of consecutive terms is simple.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I wrote "PDF" when I meant to say "CDF" -- cumulative density function.  "PMF" is probability mass function, the probability of each value.